# Run-time Error 1004 when I try to delete rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have been using similar code to this on office 2003 but I have recently upgraded to Office 2010 and the code has stopped working. I have been stepping through the code and it errors when the code tries to delete the rows specified by nStart and nEnd. I get a Run-time Error 1004. I have searched the forums but I cannot find a solution. The problem is in the last couple rows of code.

The code is designed to copy data from a large data set and break it down into separate spreadsheets for each directorate within the organisation. Once the first group has been copied across the data is deleted from the master sheet and the process starts over until it meets an empty cell.

I have left a couple of attempts at fixing the problem but turned them into comments just in case I was getting close.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Appraisal_Split()

Dim wbI As Workbook, wbO As Workbook
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO1 As Worksheet
Dim wsO2 As Worksheet
Dim nRow As Long
Dim nStart As Long, nEnd As Long
Dim Dir As String

'Stop screen from flickering
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'~~> Source/Input Workbook
Set wbI = ThisWorkbook
'~~> Source/Input Sheet
Set wsI = wbI.Sheets("Individual Data")

' Define what directorate to search for.

Do While Cells(2, 1).Value <> ""
Dir = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, "A").Value

' Find where Directorate data starts.
For nRow = 1 To 10000
If Range("A" & nRow).Value = Dir Then
nStart = nRow
Exit For
End If
Next nRow

' Find where the Directorate data ends.
For nRow = nStart To 10000
If Range("A" & nRow).Value <> Dir Then
nEnd = nRow
Exit For
End If
Next nRow
nEnd = nEnd - 1

'~~> Destination/Output Workbook
Workbooks.Open ("G:\Workforce\Reports\Weekly & Monthly & Quarterly Reports\Appraisal  Reports\Appraisal Macro\Department Template.xlsx")

Set wbO = Workbooks("Department Template.xlsx")

With wbO
    '~~> Set the relevant sheet to where you want to paste
    Set wsO1 = wbO.Sheets("Data")

    '~~>. Save the file
    .SaveAs Filename:="G:\Workforce\Reports\Weekly & Monthly & Quarterly Reports\Appraisal Reports\Appraisal Macro\Temp" & "\" & Dir

    '~~> Copy the range
    wsI.Range("A" & nStart & ":I" & nEnd).Copy

    '~~> Paste it data to Cell A1 of new workbook.
    wsO1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wsO1.Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    wsO1.Range("A2").AutoFilter

    ' Copy the column width for the first 9 columns
        Dim i As Integer
            For i = 1 To 9
            wsO1.Columns(i).ColumnWidth = wsI.Columns(i).ColumnWidth
        Next i

    ' Update Summary Pivot Table
        Set wsO2 = wbO.Sheets("Summary")
        wsO2.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable

    '~~> Summary Formulas
        wsO2.Range("F4:J4").Select

        Dim LR As Long

        LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("F4:J4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F4:J" & LR)

        Columns("B:F").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Rows("2:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    ' Set workbook protection, save and close.
    wsO1.Protect Password:="workforce1", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    wsO1.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
    wsO2.Protect Password:="workforce1", DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True,     Scenarios:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    wsO2.EnableSelection = xlNoRestrictions
    wbO.Close savechanges:=True
End With

**' Delete directorate data from input file
wsI.Rows(nStart, nEnd).Delete
   ' .Rows(nStart & ":" & nEnd).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
   ' .Range(nStart, nEnd).EntireRow.Delete**


' Workbooks("Trust Template with Macro.xls").Activate
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming nStart and nEnd are valid:

```
wsI.Range(nStart & ":" & nEnd).Delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format for the range you wish to delete is incorrect.  The Intellisense help may be useful in seeing the problem.  But try a variation of one of these, depending on whether you want to delete the entire row, or just the area where your data is located:

```
With wsI
   .Range(.Cells(nStart, 1), .Cells(nEnd, 1)).EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

or

```
With wsI
    .Range(.Cells(nStart, "A"), .Cells(nEnd, "C")).Delete shift:=xlUp
End With
```

Comment: Thank you both for your feed back, I have tried all answers with no luck. To make surre that the variable are valid I used MsgBox nStart and MsgBox nEnd this outputed the correct values. I also tried to just Select the range using:    wsI.Range("A" & nStart & ":I" & nEnd).Select which also work. So it appears the only thing that generates an error is the .Delete.

Comment: Copy and paste (do NOT type it) so I can see exactly how you are using either of my suggestions; and also the values that nStart and nEnd are returning.